# RVM install error, can't install latest version

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby v 1.9.3 via RVM, and I get this error when I run the command:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p0 to /Users/shaboy/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/shaboy/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/shaboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-          
install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/shaboy/.rvm/usr ',
please read /Users/shaboy/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

configure.log

```
[2012-02-12 16:14:10]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/shaboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --    
disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/shaboy/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/shaboy/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: can you show us the contents of the log?

Comment: What's in `/Users/shaboy/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log`?

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? The key bit seems to be this: "checking whether the C compiler works... no". To clarify: on OSX you don't have a C compiler installed by default. In order to get one, you must install Apple's Xcode package.

Comment: i do currently have Xcode installed.

Comment: Ok. Next question - what's in the 'config.log' that 'configure.log' refers to?

Comment: the longest file i have ever seen. whats your email address? i'll send it along

Comment: Put it up on http://pastebin.com/ or the like and then put a link here. Also, you may get better/quicker help by going onto rvm's IRC channel. It's #rvm on Freenode.

Comment: error is all set. ruby -v 1.9.2 installed via zsh. dont know why i was enocuntering these errors earlier but everything seems to be working now. thanks @Telemachus

Answer (score 0):

There was no stable version of ruby on those days but it is stable.Although it giving some

warrnings yet so please you should use ruby 1.9.2 which is stable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install XCode 4.1 and set an environment variable `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`. This is the best solution if you want to install all the version of ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 and have no problem with gems.

`clang` solution with XCode > 4.1 or `osx-gcc-installer` allows you to build only ruby 1.9.3 and will fail build ruby-debugger gems, it will also cause lots of random crashed with mysql2 gems.